# WSO2 Fault sequence does not return using local transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and my configurations in axis2.xml are default:

```
<transportReceiver name="local" class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportReceiver"/>
<transportSender name="local" class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender"/>
```

Calling a proxy in the same JVM, when a fault occurs, the `faultSequence` can not return a response by the `send` mediator, and I receive a timeout.

The configuration below not solve my problem:

```
<faultSequence>
  ...
  <header name="To" action="remove"/>
  <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <send/>
</faultSequence>
```

Otherwise, changing the 'local transport' by 'http transport', everything works well.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [<respond/>](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Respond+Mediator) mediator instead of the above to send the response back to client.

Comment: Good idea, but the version that I'm using is 4.6.0. The 'Send Mediator' is available only in releases above 4.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I did an upgrade to the ESB 4.9.0 version and I solved my problem. I saw some posts on internet like this and I think that is a bug in the old WSO2 version.